# Question concerning two independent, normally distributed random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose X~N(10,5) and Y~N(5,4) and X,Y are independent of each other. Find the following probability P[(2X-Y)>18]

Comment: Hint: First, determine the distribution of $2X - Y$, using the fact that $X,Y$ are independent to each other.  Then, evaluate $P(2X - Y > 18)$

Comment: can you tell me how to calculate the answers tho/???

Comment: Andre gave you some hints for you.

Comment: it helped me to get var and mean of the equation W but i still dont know how to figure out the probability

Answer (score 2):

Let $W=2X-Y$. Then $W$ has mean $(2)(10)-5$.

Becuase $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $2X-Y$ has normal distribution with variance $2^2\text{Var}(X)+(-1)^2\text{Var}(Y)$.

Now that you know that $W$ is normal, and you know its mean and variance, I am sure you can find $\Pr(W\gt 18)$.

Comment: thank you very much, i found Mean of W = 15 and Var of W = 24.

Comment: but i still dont know how to get probability finally

Comment: We have $\Pr(W\gt 18)=\Pr\left(Z\gt \frac{18-15}{\sqrt{24}}\right)$, where $Z$ is standard normal. Now you can use a table of the standard normal, or software. Your table will probably have values for $\Pr(Z\le z)$, for various values of $z$. We have $\frac{3}{\sqrt{24}}\approx 0.61$. My table gives $\Pr(Z\le 0.61)\approx 0.729$. So the probability that $Z\gt 0.61$ is about $1-0.729$.

Comment: ahhhhh im using z score.... .no one was telling me to use this and i forgot this for long time lol thank you verymuch

Comment: You are welcome.